# Pullback in crystalline cohomology

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, crystalline-cohomology

Let $f:X\to Y$ be a morphism of schemes over a perfect field $k$. If $f$ is flat, is the pullback $f^*$ from quasi-coherent crystals on $Y$ to quasi-coherent crystals on $X$ exact? This is pullback of modules, that is $E\mapsto f^{-1}E\otimes_{f^{-1}\mathcal{O}_{Y/k}}\mathcal{O}_{X/k}$ for every $\mathcal{O}_{Y/k}$-module $E$. Equivalently, is $f^{-1}\mathcal{O}_{Y/k}\to \mathcal{O}_{X/k}$ flat?

I really cannot find this anywhere. I went over Berthelot's thesis and also the notes of Berthelot-Ogus. If $f^*$ is not exact, I would have expected a study of the derived functors.

What if we assume that $f$ is smooth? Then étale locally it has sections, maybe this can be used to prove flatness.